# Update cart - mysql table update - while loop

Tags: php, mysql, cart

new guy here!
I am building a custom shopping cart driven by mysql and i am trying to update my cart item by item in terms of quantity. It seems that i am doing something wrong because when i try to update the quantity it only update the last item. I am posting the code below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

1.cart.php:

```
    $sql = "select * from orders";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "Στοιχεία: ".$num;
    ?>
    <form name="cart" method="post" action="updatecart.php">
      <table border="2">
        <tr>
          <td>Α/Α</td>
          <td>img_name</td>
          <td>Reprints</td>
          <td>Color</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if($num){
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php  echo $row['item_id']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['img_name']; ?></td>
                  <td><input type="number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>"></td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<? echo $row['item_id']; ?>">
                  <td><?php echo $row['color']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
        }

            ?>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Cart" />
      <input type="button" name="2checkout" value="Proceed to Checkout" />
</form>
```

2.updatecart.php

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<?php
    $database_name = "vog";
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","toor");
    mysql_select_db($database_name);

    $num = 2; //na to ferw me session meta edw!
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        $item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
        $i=1;

        while($i<=$num){
            $item_id = $_POST['item_id'][$i];
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
            $sql2 = "update orders SET quantity = '$quantity' where item_id = '$item_id' ";
            $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error in query: $result2");
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if(isset($result2)){
        header("Location:cart.php");
    }
?>
```

So far it updates just the last record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in #1.cart.php use the inputs as array:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity[<?php  echo $row['item_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id[<?php  echo $row['item_id']; ?>]" value="<? echo $row['item_id']; ?>">
```

and in #2.updatecart.php: process it like

```
 foreach($_POST['item_id'] as $key => $id){

 $item_id = $id;
 $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
 $sql2 = "update orders SET quantity = '$quantity' where item_id = '$item_id' ";
 $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error in query: $result2");
 $i++;

 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.It works as it is supposed to! Now i would propably need to add protection measurements against sql injections.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the names of the fields in your HTML form:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="<? echo $row['item_id']; ?>">
```

I think you meant to call them `quantity[]` and `item_id[]` instead, so they will and up as arrays in your `$_POST` variable later on, now they overwrite eachother, making `$_POST['item_id']` only contain the last id in the database.

Comment: And the union of PHP programmers everywhere called me to add a comment: before you write another line of PHP code, first read up about SQL injection. This code leaves your database wide open to hackers. Check http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: What do you suggest, in terms of anti-sql-injection measurements?

Comment: @EvanSap : use mysql_real_escape_string function .. also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @EvanSap Whenever you embed a string from one language (for instance PHP) into another language (for instance SQL or HTML), you need to convert the string into the proper language or you will experience problems. To go from a PHP string to SQL, you use `mysql_real_escape_string`. To go from a PHP string to HTML, you use `htmlspecialchars`. Not only does this prevent hackers from abusing your system, it also solves problems when someone wants to write `Mac Donald's` to the database, or `I <3 burgers` into the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell PHP that you're using an array for your submitted form items. The way to do this is to make the name of each input `quantity[]`. You can also place the item ID directly in the array as a key. In `cart.php` you can do this in your loop:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity[<?php echo $row['item_id']; ?>]" 
                     value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>"/>
```

In effect, this will putput something like:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity[2]" value="1" />
<input type="number" name="quantity[4]" value="1" />
<input type="number" name="quantity[8]" value="2" />
```

i.e. 1 of item 2, 1 of item 4 and 2 of item 8.

Then, in `updatecart.php` you can read in the array and process it in a loop.

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){ 
   foreach ($_POST['quantity'] as $item_id => $item_qty) {
       $item_id  = (int)$item_id;
       $item_qty = (int)$item_qty;

       $sql2 = "update orders SET quantity = '$item_qty' where item_id = '$item_id' ";
       mysql_query($sql2);
   }
}
```

Comment: You can thank people by voting up their answers, and accepting one. =)